# Use external non-installed TrueType font from TTF file to write text on Canvas

Tags: delphi

I have a special TrueType font in a TTF file which is not registered on users' PCs. Can I place it as an embedded resource somewhere inside my Delphi project and write text on a `Canvas`  **without** having the users install the font? Can someone provide a working example?

Suppose I have

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.MoveTo(20, 100);

  Canvas.Font.Name := 'CustomFontFromTTFNotRegistered';
  Canvas.Font.Color := clMaroon;
  Canvas.Font.Style := [];
  Canvas.Font.Height := 64;
  Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, 'test');
end;
```

Comment: Use `AddFontResourceEx()` and `CreateFontIndirect()` as per [load a ttf font with the Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757227/load-a-ttf-font-with-the-windows-api).

Comment: Thanks, that answer is for Win32 API/C++. I'm a Delphi newbie. Would it be possible to provide a working example in Delphi for how to do this `CreateFontIndirect`?

Comment: You should be able to see a [delphi example here](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=21032.15), detailing suggested commands from @AmigoJack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the loop on this (much thanks to Remy Lebeau for his summary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224624/loading-font-from-resource-file)), the following worked for me. I'm adding a dynamic resource (no external files anywhere, everything in-memory/embedded) in `FormCreate` and then removing it in `FormDestroy`, using the Windows API In-Memory Font functions `AddFontMemResourceEx` / `RemoveFontMemResourceEx`.

First, go to **Project -> Resources and Images** and add your external fonts. Give them sequential IDs, e.g. **1**, ... This will add the resources to the project.
[image]

Define the below variable in your .pas file, above all the functions/procedures. It will store the handle to the loaded font (you'll need it later for removal). If other fonts are used, define similar handles.

```
// Font handles
handleFontExternal1: NativeUInt;
```

Add these functions to Load/UnLoad Font(s). In this example, only 1 external font is specified.

```
procedure LoadFonts();  // Note: using "1" to refer to Font #1
var
  ResStream1 : TResourceStream;
  FontsCount1 : DWORD;
  Result1 : Boolean;
begin
  ResStream1 := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(hInstance, 1, RT_FONT); // This is Resource ID 1
  try
    handleFontExternal1 := AddFontMemResourceEx(ResStream1.Memory, ResStream1.Size, nil, @FontsCount1);
    Result1 := (handleFontExternal1 <> 0);
    // If you want to show a message box on failure, you can check Result1
    // otherwise the font is loaded now; handleFontExternal1 is ready    
  finally
    ResStream1.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure UnLoadFonts();
var
  Result1: Boolean;
begin
  if handleFontExternal1 > 0 then
    Result1 := RemoveFontMemResourceEx(handleFontExternal1);
    // once again you can check Result1 and show any failure messages if desired
end;
```

Now call these from `FormCreate` / `FormDestroy`, hooked up to the Form's Create & Destroy events.

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadFonts();
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnLoadFonts();
end;
```